# Pass a lazy parameter to function

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I have a function that needs to call another function to do work. I want to delay the second function call until needed. The reason is that sometimes the second function call is not needed.

The code looks like this:

```
suspend fun doWork(list: List<A>) {
    if(list.isEmpty()) return
    
    secondFunction()
}
```

However, `secondFunction()` has to be determined by the caller of the function. Is there a way to do this maybe by using lambda?

Comment: This is explained int he documentation here. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a lambda to delay the execution of your second function until you need the value.

```
suspend fun doWork(
   list: List<A>,
   lambdaFunction: suspend () -> Unit
) {
    ...
    lambdaFunction()
}
```

Or you can have it return a value.

```
suspend fun doWork(
   list: List<A>,
   lambdaFunction: suspend () -> String
) {
    ...
    val result = lambdaFunction()
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
doWork(
   list = list, 
   lambdaFunction = { secondFunction() }
)
```

I also made it `suspend` because I saw you using `suspend`. You don't have to use `suspend`.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you want can be solved via the `Observer Pattern`

Ill show you in `rxKotlin`

```
val subject = PublishSubject.create<Observable<List<A>>>()

subject.subscribeBy(
    onNext = { doWork(it) },
    onError =  { it.printStackTrace() },
    onComplete = { println("Done!") }
)
```

And when the list is ready.

```
subject.oNext(list)
```

The doWork function will be called and you don't need to block the use of `secondFunction` as list will contain the values.